# Call a "local" function within module.exports from another function in module.exports?

Tags: node.js, express

How do you call a function from within another function in a `module.exports` declaration?

app.js

```
var bla = require('./bla.js');
console.log(bla.bar());
```

bla.js

```
module.exports = {

  foo: function (req, res, next) {
    return ('foo');
  },

  bar: function(req, res, next) {
    this.foo();
  }

}
```

I'm trying to access the function `foo` from within the function `bar`, and I'm getting:

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'foo'

If I change `this.foo()` to just `foo()` I get:

> ReferenceError: foo is not defined

Comment: I tested your code and have no errors. The bar function returns undefined because have no return statement. Are you sure you are testing correctly?

Comment: Tested in node version `v8.12.0` and does no longer throw the error. `bar` has no return statement so running `console.log(bla.bar())` simply returns `undefined`

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Change `this.foo()` to `module.exports.foo()`

Comment: @NamNguyen Calling `exports.foo()` seems a little bit awkward and hard to read.

Comment: I think that this is better than the accepted answer. If you define functions outside of the exports scope, it adds an extra level of indirection, and while it can be desirable sometimes, it makes it more complicated, to refactor, e.g. rename the function, of find usage of the function, etc.

Comment: `module.exports.foo()` and `exports.foo()` do not work for me with Node.js v5.8.0.

Comment: exports.foo() is not working but module.exports.foo() is working with NodeJS v6.9.1

Comment: This worked for me but instead of doing `module.exports = {...}` I had to do `exports.myFunction = function()` for each of the exported methods.

Comment: `exports.foo` only works if you define an `exports` varible that references the `module.exports` object  `const exports = module.exports = {}` and then set functions `foo` and `bar` as its methods `exports.foo = function() {}` and `exports.bar = function (){ exports.foo() }` here to reference `foo` in the `bar` use `exports.foo`. If you want to reference `foo` from `bar` inside  `module.exports` object then use `module.exports.foo` inside `bar`.

Comment: @k00k: Can you please put link of your own answer to your question? It'll help us to get it over there itself instead of scrolling down to here. Thanks :)

Comment: You don't need your exports variable to reference module.exports, it is done for you: 

"The exports variable is available within a module's file-level scope, and is assigned the value of module.exports before the module is evaluated.

It allows a shortcut, so that module.exports.f = ... can be written more succinctly as exports.f = ..."  https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_exports_shortcut

Comment: its weird cant use `this` in module.exports

Answer (score 205):

You could declare your functions outside of the `module.exports` block.

```
var foo = function (req, res, next) {
  return ('foo');
}

var bar = function (req, res, next) {
  return foo();
}
```

Then:

```
module.exports = {
  foo: foo,
  bar: bar
}
```

Comment: what if I wanted to access properties of the object from the method?

Comment: I'm getting TypeError: yourClass.youMethod is not a function when I did this.  I'm using node version 6.9.1.  Do you have to have a return statement?  I do not have return statements since all my code is async in the functions.

Comment: Nice comparison of different styles --  https://gist.github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/10848413

Comment: Or, more concisely using ES6, `module.exports = { foo, bar, }`

Answer (score 132):

You can also do this to make it more concise and readable. This is what I've seen done in several of the well written open sourced modules:

```
var self = module.exports = {

  foo: function (req, res, next) {
    return ('foo');
  },

  bar: function(req, res, next) {
    self.foo();
  }

}
```

Comment: Is this Node.js version specific? I am trying this with v5.8.0 and it is logging undefined.

Comment: @doublejosh Did... did you read the question? It's asking how you call one exported function from another. It has _nothing to do_ with access restrictions.

Comment: Yes I read it, please re-read. This answer makes foo() exported with the module, which goes against the point of a "local" function only called within the module.

Comment: This works great. I actually need foo() exported to be used outside, but also need to call it within sibling function. Thank you!

Answer (score 68):

You can also save a reference to module's global scope outside the (module.)exports.somemodule definition:

```
var _this = this;

exports.somefunction = function() {
   console.log('hello');
}

exports.someotherfunction = function() {
   _this.somefunction();
}
```

Comment: It's more cleaner solution!

Comment: no need for the _this and you can simply use this where you need it

Comment: used `this` directly, no need to declare `_this`

Comment: That suggestion is useful once `this` is no longer the right `this`. (Promises and callbacks)

Comment: I like this solution the best because it also gives an example of scoping in NodeJS modules.

Answer (score 43):

Another option, and closer to the original style of the OP, is to put the object you want to export into a variable and reference that variable to make calls to other methods in the object. You can then export that variable and you're good to go.

```
var self = {
  foo: function (req, res, next) {
    return ('foo');
  },
  bar: function (req, res, next) {
    return self.foo();
  }
};
module.exports = self;
```

Answer (score 28):

```
const Service = {
  foo: (a, b) => a + b,
  bar: (a, b) => Service.foo(a, b) * b
}

module.exports = Service
```

Comment: This is particularly usable because your code there is calling `Service.foo()`, and your client code will also be calling `Service.foo()` with the same naming.

Comment: This is a perfect answer!

Comment: I used it with Salesforce lwc and it works perfectly, I like this clean method

Answer (score 21):

Starting with **Node.js version 13** you can take advantage of [ES6 Modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html).

```
export function foo() {
    return 'foo';
}

export function bar() {
    return foo();
}
```

---

Following the Class approach:

```
class MyClass {

    foo() {
        return 'foo';
    }

    bar() {
        return this.foo();
    }
}

module.exports = new MyClass();
```

This will instantiate the class only once, due to Node's module caching:
https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching

Comment: and how does one call a static method with this approach?

Comment: @CodeofGod Just call it as you would call any other static method. In this case, if `foo` was static you would call it from inside `bar` like this: `MyClass.foo()`.

Comment: yeah i get that, but how would you call it from a controller that is importing it like... const oAccounts = require("...");

Comment: You can export the actual class, not an instance of the class. That way you can use its static methods. If you then need to use its instance methods though, then you will have to instantiate the class in your controller.

Answer (score 8):

To fix your issue, i have made few changes in bla.js and it is working,

```
var foo= function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('inside foo');
  return ("foo");
}

var  bar= function(req, res, next) {
  this.foo();
}
module.exports = {bar,foo};
```

and no modification in app.js

```
var bla = require('./bla.js');
console.log(bla.bar());
```

Comment: In the function bar, this.foo() doesn't work... it needs to be foo()

Answer (score 0):

What I do is to create a standalone `foo` function and reference it in both places.

That way, it prevents any issue with `this` irrespective of using an arrow or regular function

```
function foo(req,res,next) {
  return ('foo');
}
```

Then I can reference `foo` at both places

```
module.exports = {

  foo, // ES6 for foo:foo

  bar: function(req, res, next) {
    foo();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do like this, you will be losing your `this` object reference inside your calling function.
For eg:

```
    module.exports.a = function () {
      return true
    }
    
    module.exports.b = function() {
      return this.a();
    }
```

here you will get the issue because when you call this.a(), it is referencing the `this` object of the `b` function.

To solve this your have to store your `this` object reference somewhere or use the arrow function, because the arrow function doesn't have there own `this` object so it will always reference the outer `this` object

To solve this, modify your function like this

```
    module.exports.a = function () {
      return true
    }
    
    module.exports.b = () => {
      return this.a();
    }
```