# Running JavaScript on Ubuntu terminal gives no output

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, ubuntu

I am trying to execute a javascript function on a cloud ubuntu machine. Here's the code:

```
exports.msg = function(){
    console.log('This is a test function');
}
```

Now whenever I run this using nodejs on Windows using the command `node test.js` assuming the filename is `test.js` it works perfectly <strike>and prints the output</strike>. But whenever I install nodejs (Version 4.x) on Ubuntu and try running `nodejs test.js` the console runs with no output what so ever. No errors, no output, no nothing.
Originally I am referring to [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/creating-node-modules) to do this.
I referred to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532960/how-do-you-run-javascript-script-through-the-terminal) but I don't want to use Rhino. I want to use Nodejs. What am I doing wrong.
P.S. I know that nodejs runs using `nodejs` on Ubuntu and using `node` on Windows so this is definitely not the problem. Plus if you try running `node test.js` on Ubuntu without diverting the path of the executable from nodejs it will give an error.
I really don't know what I am missing here. Does nodejs has some log file in Ubuntu that I should check for the output? I tried checking the system log files with no luck.
Thanks.

Comment: you need to call the function for it to get executed

Comment: Can you please tell me a sample command to run?

Comment: I am really sorry but I just tried it and it gives an error "msg is not defined" on windows

Comment: your code should be var msg = function(){ console.log('This is a test function'); } msg();

Comment: Awesome it works. Please add it as an answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: So basically I can't run an exported function from console right?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10462223/call-a-local-function-within-module-exports-from-another-function-in-module-ex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your code should be

```
var msg = function(){ 
  console.log('This is a test function');
}
msg();
```

to call the function locally define it first as local or you can also do

```
 exports.msg = function(){
   console.log('This is a test function');
 }
 exports.msg();
```

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution that doesn't require changing the code
I used `node -e require('./test.js').msg()` 
The `-e` evaluates the node environment and requiring the module from it's path and calling the function gives the desired result. This is in case you would like to run an exported function.